# How to do stuff before 'propagating' actual link click

Tags: jquery

So I have a `click` event on certain kind of links. What I need is to do some stuff when link is clicked but before it actually goes to that link. Setting location to link's href doesn't work because I need it work same as when `a` has `target` set to `_blank`. So far, I've tried quite a few things.$("

```
$(".things a").click(function (e, pass)
{
    if (pass != 1)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        func_to_do_stuff($(this))
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
})

function func_to_do_stuff(link)
{
    //do stuff
    link.trigger('click', [1]);
}
```

And while the click is triggered by `func_to_do_stuff` and 1 is passed as second argument, it actually won't do what I expect it to do (emulate a click and open the link in new tab (link has `target="blank"`)). What am I doing wrong?

Another thing to achieve what I need, would be to delay the actual propagation of default click event until I'm done with my stuff (not effects)

Comment: Triggering the click in jQuery just runs the jQuery handler, it doesn't emulate what actually clicking on the link does.

Comment: You want to do something during the capture event phase?